# kubectl - How to edit service spec type to LoadBalancer via command line?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a k8s service of type clusterIP.. i need to change the below configuration via CLI

1. the http port to https port
2. the port number
3. the type to Load Balancer

Is there a way to do it..?

Comment: Do you have the original YAML specification in source control?  Best way is to edit it there, commit it, and `kubectl apply -f`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't remove the existing port, but you *can* add the HTTPs port and also change the type using [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/)

Example:

```
kubectl patch svc <my_service> -p '{"spec": {"ports": [{"port": 443,"targetPort": 443,"name": "https"},{"port": 80,"targetPort": 80,"name": "http"}],"type": "LoadBalancer"}}'
```

If you don't want to create JSON on the command line, create a yaml file like so:

```
ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    name: "https"
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: "http"
  type: LoadBalancer
```

And then do:

```
kubectl patch svc <my_service> --patch "$(cat patch.yaml)"
```

Answer (score 21):

`kubectl edit svc <service_name> -n <namespace>`

i - to edit the service

ESC, :wq -  update your service

Use `kubectl patch svc <service_name> -p '{"spec": ....}'` if you don't want the prompt.

Comment: Awesome.. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: The solution does not works on Powershell.

Answer (score 3):

The original solution does not works on powershell. Here is the following we need to do in order to make it work.

[kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/)

**Powershell:**

`kubectl patch svc <my_service> -p '{\"spec\": {\"ports\": [{\"port\": 443,\"targetPort\": 443,\"name\": \"https\"},{\"port\": 80,\"targetPort\": 80,\"name\": \"http\"}],\"type\": \"LoadBalancer\"}}'`.

*Notice the \ for powershell use case.*

**Bash:**

`kubectl patch svc <my_service> -p '{"spec": {"ports": [{"port": 443,"targetPort": 443,"name": "https"},{"port": 80,"targetPort": 80,"name": "http"}],"type": "LoadBalancer"}}'`